# hook_mail_alter() doesn't remove the Return-Path, Sender, and Reply-To headers

Tags: 8, hooks, emails

I want to remove the *Return-Path*, *Sender*, and *Reply-To* headers from the sent emails. I am trying to achieve this using the following code, but the headers aren't removed from the email.

```php
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  unset($message['headers']['Return-Path']);
  unset($message['headers']['Sender']);
  unset($message['headers']['Reply-To']);
}
```

We are using default PHP mailer of Drupal 8 and the SMTP module . We are trying to fire the Test Mail via the SMTP module after entering credentials. But it seems we are not able to modify the headers from `hook_mail_alter()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So much left unsaid ... such as what @Mail plugin(s) you're using.

Comment: We are using default PHP mailer of Drupal 8 and the SMTP module . We are trying to fire the Test Mail via the SMTP module after entering credentials. But it seems we are not able to modify the headers from hook_mail_alter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SMTP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module always sets certain headers which cannot be unset. See the following lines from  `Drupal\smtp\Plugin\Mail\SMTPMailSystem`:

```
$headers['Sender'] = $from;
$headers['Return-Path'] = $from;
$headers['Reply-To'] = $from;
```

This is to make it compatible with Drupal core which does the same from what I can tell.

For more control, you can use the module [PHPMailer SMTP](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpmailer_smtp) instead which explicitly unsets the `Return-Path` header to comply with [RFC 5321](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-4.4).

It also makes no assumptions about which extra headers should be present (beyond the required ones) and only sets them if they are added elsewhere.

The following would work if the case of the headers match:

```
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  unset($message['headers']['Sender']);
  unset($message['headers']['Reply-To']);
}
```

Alternatively, the following would unset headers regardless of case:

```
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  $message['headers'] = array_change_key_case($message['headers']);
  unset($message['headers']['sender']);
  unset($message['headers']['reply-to']);
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of PHPMailer SMTP.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the values from `$message['headers']` isn't sufficient, as the plugin  used to send emails could also use `$message['Return-Path']`, `$message['Sender']`, or `$message['Reply-To']` value to build the email headers. The class that is used as default plugin to send emails, [`PhpMail`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Mail%21Plugin%21Mail%21PhpMail.php/class/PhpMail/8.9.x) uses the following code, but other plugins could use different code.

```php
$site_mail = $this->configFactory->get('system.site')->get('mail');
$additional_headers = isset($message['Return-Path']) && ($site_mail === $message['Return-Path'] || static::_isShellSafe($message['Return-Path'])) ? '-f' . $message['Return-Path'] : '';
$mail_result = @mail($message['to'], $mail_subject, $mail_body, $mail_headers, $additional_headers);
```

Since the email plugin is used to send the email after the `hook_mail_alter()` implementations are invoked, and since the email plugin can add one of those headers to its discretion, there isn't any warranty the email is sent without those headers. Assuming the email plugin adds only those headers when `$message` or `$message['headers']` contains a value for them, the following code should work.

```php
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  unset($message['Return-Path']);
  unset($message['Sender']);
  unset($message['Reply-To']);
  unset($message['headers']['Return-Path']);
  unset($message['headers']['Sender']);
  unset($message['headers']['Reply-To']);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add that the RFC says headers are case insensitive, so for example "unset($message['headers']['Return-Path']);" is insufficient - the header key could be "return-Path", so your unset wouldn't do anything. Likewise, the @Mail plugin could be assuming a certain casing, so even if the plugin tried to respect your choice the case you use could trip it up. Bottom line is what apademo said above: "Since the email plugin is used to send the email after the hook_mail_alter() implementations are invoked ... there isn't any warranty the email is sent without those headers."

Answer (score -1):

Use function hook_mail($key, &$message, $params) instead. Also, you would need additional $key I believe to distinguish for which functionality is the mail being sent.

Then this hook would be triggered when sending the mail manually:

```
$send = true;
$mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
$result = $mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to, $langcode, $params, null, $send);
```

I would suggest using Swiftmailer, it omits all of the manual work.

Comment: I take the OP wants to remove those headers from every email. `hook_mail()` would not help with that.

Comment: Even if the OP wanted to remove the Return-Path, Sender, and Reply-To headers from the email sent by a module the OP wrote, or by a specific module, this answer doesn't say how to achieve that.